Find all connected pixels in GEE
I have two burned area maps in Google Earth Engine. I want to find and extract the pixels spatially connected to the previous year's burned area. Hereafter, I want to extract all the pixels spatially connected to the current year's burned area if they were connected to the previous year's burned area.
I have looked and tried the following:
var image_13 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
                .map(applyScaleFactors)
                .map(maskL8sr)
                .map(addNBRL8)
                .filterBounds(TP)
                .filterDate('2013-05-01', '2013-06-30')
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50))
                .mean();

// Load the Landsat 8 surface reflectance collection
var image_14 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
                .map(applyScaleFactors)
                .map(maskL8sr)
                .map(addNBRL8)
                .filterBounds(TP)
                .filterDate('2014-05-01', '2014-06-30')
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50))
                .mean();

// Load the Landsat 8 surface reflectance collection
var image_15 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
                .map(applyScaleFactors)
                .map(maskL8sr)
                .map(addNBRL8)
                .filterBounds(TP)
                .filterDate('2015-05-01', '2015-06-30')
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50))
                .mean();

// Calculate the dNBR
var preFire13 = image_13.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B7']);
var postFire14 = image_14.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B7']);
var dNBR14 = preFire13.subtract(postFire14);

var preFire14 = image_14.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B7']);
var postFire15 = image_15.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B7']);
var dNBR15 = preFire14.subtract(postFire15);

// Function to find connected pixels
function findConnectedPixels(image, referenceImage) {
  // Convert the image to an integer type
  image = image.toInt();

  // Calculate connected pixel count using 8-connected rules
  var connectedPixels = image.connectedPixelCount({
    maxSize: 100,  // Set a reasonable maximum size
    eightConnected: false
  });

  // Mask the connected pixels based on the reference image
  var connectedPixelsMasked = connectedPixels.updateMask(referenceImage);

  return connectedPixelsMasked;
}

// Find connected pixels in dNBR15 connected to dNBR14
var connectedPixels_15 = findConnectedPixels(dNBR15, dNBR14);

// Find all connected pixels in dNBR15 starting from those connected to dNBR14
var connectedPixels_all = findConnectedPixels(dNBR15, connectedPixels_15);

This does not work as it generates the same pixels detected in dNBR14 as the adjacent pixels in connectedPixels_15, see figure.
I need to extract all the blue area that connect to dNBR14 and hereafter dNBR15 in the last picture.
How can I do so in GEE?

